# how to use order by clause for case insensitive listing in hibernate named query

Tags: hibernate, sql-order-by, hql

I have a user table

**Users**

```
userId firstName
1      A
2      B
3      a
```

My SQL query (`select * from User order by firstName`) returns correct result:

```
A
a
B
```

HQL named query (`Select up from UserProfile up, User u where up.userId  = u.userId order by upper(u.firstName)`) gives:
    A
    B
    a

Can somebody explain me this behavior and a workaround to get case insensitive sorting working (note: *using upper function does not help*).
I noticed `Criteria has ignoreCase` function but I do not want to use criteria but HQL query

Answer (score 2):

**SQL**

```
SELECT UPPER(username) FROM users order by username;
```

**HIbernate**

For example with Hibernate you can use `LOWER` function to `p.name in ORDER BY`:

```
select u from Users as u order by LOWER(u.name)
```

I assume above is not guaranteed to work with all JPA implementations, because argument to `ORDER BY` is not one of the following:

1. A state_field_path_expression that evaluates to an orderable state field of an entity or embeddable class abstract schema type designated in the SELECT clause by one of the following:

   • a general_identification_variable

   • a single_valued_object_path_expression
2. A state_field_path_expression that evaluates to the same state field of the same entity or embeddable abstract schema type as a `state_field_path_expression` in the `SELECT clause`
3. A result_variable that refers to an orderable item in the `SELECT clause` for which the same result_variable has been specified. This may be the result of an aggregate_expression, a scalar_expression, or a `state_field_path_expression` in the `SELECT clause`. For example, the four queries below are legal.

If it does not work with JPA implementation you use, you have to use following query:

```
select u, LOWER(u.name) AS name_order 
from Users as u 
order by name_order
```

Drawback is that result of the query is list of object arrays, first element in each list being instance of Plan entity and second element to be discarded.